# Serena Dimensions Merge

Tags: merge, serena

In serena dimensions, there are two parallel streams (Stream A and Stream B) from the same ancestor. I require to merge few modified files from Stream A to Stream B. Can someone guide as how this can be done.

Comment: in my experience with Dimensions the only solution is to put the whole thing in the bin and upgrade to sccs, sorry. Have you tried Serena support?

Answer (score 1):

None tool provides "automatic merging".

Suppose you have stream A and stream B, same item in different revisions: X 1.0 - production, X 1.1 - Stream A, X 1.2 stream B

First you must choose wich stream will get the "final merged" revision. You can use a third stream, just for all merges, regression tests and action to production.

Usualy you create a "third" version, (ex: X 1.3 if you choose merge based on production), or use a existent stream revision (ex: X.1.1.1, if you chose merge on existent revision 1.1 on stream A).

Use "compare" tool to check differences and proceed merging.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done locally, by having both streams updated each in its own folder (I assume you have them both as this). Locally merge your changes from Origin to Destination stream (can be all or just the selected files). Make sure that nothing was broken on the Destination stream and make a deliver or check in of the Destination stream.

A good practices is to have all items written, completed or baselined in your Origin stream, whichever makes more sense in your project, prior the merging of the streams, and then as a double check you can Get your Destination stream from the server into a different path and verify that all the changes are merged and nothing was broken. Also action the items as written, completed or baselined in the Destination stream once this final check was successful.